# union on same table in laravel not working

Tags: laravel, union

```
public function getLatestList(){

$paginate = 10;

$data1 = DB::table('research_management')

->join('client','client.id','=','research_management.industry')

->select('research_management.*','client.image_link as image_link')

->where('delete_status','!=',2)

->orderBy('id','desc');

$data = DB::table('research_management1')

->join('client','client.id','=','research_management1.industry')

->select('research_management1.*','client.image_link as image_link')

->where('delete_status','!=',2)

->union($data1)

->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate($paginate);

return $data;

}
```

union not working showing error for this code

Comment: what is the error you see?

Comment: due to paginate showing error i have my 2 table 1 table have 3 lacks records 2nd one have 1000 record when i am going to union it showing error please help me out

Comment: He asked you what the error is? what does laravel was the reason for the error code, people can blindly debug error codes.

Comment: file is not exist showing when i debug.

Comment: at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'include(/vendor/composer/../filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Run.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory', '/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php', 444, array('file' => '/vendor/composer/../filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Run.php'))

Comment: "SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select count(*) as aggregate from `table2` where `delete_status` != 2) union (select * from `table1` where `delete_status` != 2) order by `id` desc) ◀"